# Delete Duplicate Rows in Oracle with combination of columns[Complex]

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have below table

```
City1   City2
NY      TO
TO      ON
TO      NY
TO      AT
AT      TO
TO      AT
```

Questions considers NY-TO and TO-NY as duplicate, Need a query in Oracle to find and remove duplicate row as mentioned above. Dont consider TO-AT & TO-AT as Duplicate. Tried several ways i.e. Subquery, Self- joins...etc. But could not solve. Anyone Query scientist here??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to add the desired output. Also, why is `TO-AT` not a duplicate if `AT-TO` exists? What is the rule for deleting duplicates - delete `TO-AT` (twice) or delete `AT-TO`?

Comment: @PeterLang I assumed that there was some additional column (primary key or timestamp) providing an order to the table and then whichever pair of values was first in the order was to be kept (as were any identical pairs) and any with the pair of values swapped was to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have some way of ordering the table (i.e. by a primary key or a timestamp):

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, city1, city2 ) AS
SELECT 1, 'NY', 'TO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'TO', 'ON' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'TO', 'NY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'TO', 'AT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'AT', 'TO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'TO', 'AT' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can do:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE  ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT CASE city1
             WHEN FIRST_VALUE( city1 )
                    OVER ( PARTITION BY LEAST( City1, City2 ),
                                        GREATEST( City1, City2 )
                           ORDER BY id )
             THEN 0
             ELSE 1
           END AS to_delete
    FROM table_name
  )
  WHERE  to_delete = 1
)
```

Which will leave:

```
ID | C1 | C2 
-------------
 1 | NY | TO
 2 | TO | ON
 4 | TO | AT
 6 | TO | AT
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem. But I did not understand how that Least and Greatest worked in combination, Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If you consider the rows `id=1,City1=NY,city2=TO` and `id=3,City1=TO,city2=NY` then `LEAST(city1,city2)=NY` and `GREATEST(city1,city2)=TO` for both rows - this means that they will be in the same partition. The `CASE` statement then checks whether the values of `city1` and `city2` are in the same position as for the first row of the partition and if they have been swapped it marks the row to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ct1.id 
FROM city_table ct1
     JOIN city_table ct2 ON CONCAT(ct1.city1+ct1.city2)=CONCAT(ct2.city1+ct2.city2)
OR CONCAT(ct1.city2+ct1.city1)=CONCAT(ct2.city1+ct2.city2)
```

You can base the JOIN on concatenation both cities

records are equal if `city1+city2` of rec1 is the same as either `city1+city2` or `city2+city1` or rec2

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly interpreted your request, this could be a solution:

`DELETE FROM your_table
      WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ID
                        FROM (SELECT ROWID ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY city1, city2 ORDER BY city1, city2) num FROM your_table)
                       WHERE num > 1)`

Otherwise, can you please give an example of the result you need.

Comment: This will not consider `City1=TO,City2=NY` and `City1=NY,City2=TO` to be duplicates.

Comment: City1 City2
NY  TO
TO  ON
TO  AT
AT  TO

Comment: In initial data you have NY-TO, TO-NY, AT-TO, TO-AT; it seems that your desired output considers NY-TO & TO-NY as duplicates (removing one), but TO-AT & AT-TO not duplicates, so I don't understand your need